# Check if the view is on the top of the screen with Selenium JavaScript web driver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, e2e-testing

I am currently using https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/api.md Selenium web driver to test website. I want to simply to check if my view is on the top of the whole screen.

I have attempted to use `isDisplay()` and `getLocationInView` to serve such purpose.

However, they are either available as absolute position of the element or display in term of element and html page level, instead of actual view itself.

I also tried  `execute()` `eval()` to run JavaScript to capture window then evaluation its axis value, since Selenium is running a real browser (Chrome).

i.e.

```
...execute("window", function(error, result) { console.log(result) };
...execute("console.log(window)", function(error, result) { console.log(result) };
...execute("return window", function(error, result) { console.log(result) };
```

However, I was only able to get `null` out of the result from these statement.

I think I must have missed a function (even though I read through their API doc more than 3 times).

I thought trigger JavaScript variable inside the testing browser, run a quick func to get axis value, and save it into a var is a viable solution.

However, I was not even able to find a working solution to just getting the `window` global var. (yes, after looked at all the relevant post indicate about executing js with selenium)

*Note and yes `executeScript` is no longer available, as least for the Selenium I am working with right now (latest version according to my package.json).

*Also important note:

I use `wd.js` as the web drive
https://github.com/admc/wd

Comment: @alecxe on yea, sry, that one got error, but I just put out what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alllrighty. I found the solution! Its pretty straight forward. I think it was just because `wd.js` using promise chain at all time, so I am not able to output anything with just eval, but I have to add asserter. so following worked perfectly.

```
browser.eval("window.pageYOffset")
      .should.eventually.equal('0')
      .nodeify(done);
```

if you want to see what's the value in `window.pageYOffset` just fail it manually.

Take me two days to understand this thing. Hopefully it save your time as well.